# Creating a primary key on table Using values from other tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create and be able to edit how the ID on a table will be created.
Suppose I have this two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consecutives]
(
        [Consecutives_ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
        [Value] [INT] NOT NULL,
        [Prefix] [VARCHAR] NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Consecutives PRIMARY KEY (Consecutives_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
        [User_ID] [INT] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        [LogIn] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
        [Pass] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY (User_ID)
);
```

is there a way to create the Primary Key on the *Users* table by using the prefix and value data on the consecutives Table and increment it once it uses that value?(via a constraint? or is it only possible via stored procedures?)

For example, having this Insert in the Consecutives table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Consecutives] ([Name], [Value], [Prefix]) 
VALUES (Users, 50, "USR-")
```

and I try to create a new user, the generated USER_ID value would be "USR-50" and the Consecutives table value updates to "51"

Comment: Huh?  Why don't you just want an `identity` column?

Comment: I asked the same.. but my teacher wants to be able to edit the next ID coming to the table.. (note that this also applies to other tables being used)

Comment: 1. The `User_ID` column you currently have is an int. 2. You have declared it as primary key twice. 3. As with your previous question, this requirement seems very strange, and introduces concurrency issues that potentially leads to errors in the best case, or wrong data in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[primary_key]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Users]
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Consecutives]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consecutives](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Prefix] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Consecutives] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LogIn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pass] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[primary_key] 
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @id varchar(50);
    DECLARE @nextid int;
    SELECT @id = (SELECT TOP 1 Prefix + cast(Value as varchar) FROM Consecutives);
    SELECT @nextid = (SELECT TOP 1 Value + 1 FROM Consecutives);

    UPDATE Users SET ID = @id WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted);
    UPDATE Consecutives SET Value = @nextid;

END
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ENABLE TRIGGER [primary_key]
GO

INSERT INTO Consecutives ([Name], [Value], [Prefix]) 
VALUES ('Users', 50, 'USR-');

INSERT INTO Users([ID],[LogIn],[Pass])
VALUES('one','login1','pass1');

INSERT INTO Users([ID],[LogIn],[Pass])
VALUES('two','login2','pass2');

INSERT INTO Users([ID],[LogIn],[Pass])
VALUES('three','login3','pass3');

SELECT * FROM Users;
SELECT * FROM Consecutives;
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, the code I posted should work.